# Как подставлять следующее число в каждом новом запросе? Python

Tags: python, list

У меня есть множество строк, которые отправляются в MySQL. Каждой строке я присваиваю отдельный ID. Это выглядит примерно так:

```
[
(1, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(2, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(3, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(4, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(5, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(6, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4")
]
```

Мне необходимо сделать, чтобы нумерация проставлялась автоматически при отправке значений.

Я пробую делать что-то вроде такого:

```
N = 500
num = list(range(1, N+1))

[
(num, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(num, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(num, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(num, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(num, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4"),
(num, "value1", "value2", "value3", value4")
]
```

Это, конечно же, не работает. Уверен, что код для такой задачи очень простой. Но я не знаю как его прописать...

Comment: MySQL позволяет сделать автоинкремент для первичных ключей. Вам это почему-то не подходит? Зачем понадобилось делать ID в python-коде?

Comment: Я отправляю значения, которые должны потом обновляться в тех же строках. А если делаю без id, то просто создаются новые строки...

Comment: А что вам мешает получить сгенерированный id из базы и потом использовать его для обновления?

Comment: Моё непонимание как это сделать

Comment: Я понимаю, что это костыльно получается. Но всё же хотелось бы на тему вопроса узнать ответ. Остальные исправления это уже вторично. Займусь ими после того, как закончу проект в первой его версии)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num = (range(0, 501))
my_list = []
for i in num:
    my_list.append((i, "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"))
```

Или в 1 строку:

```
my_list = [(i, "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4") for i in range(0, 501)]
```

Comment: Не надо сделать список (`.... for i in list(range(0, 501))]`, достаточно `... for i in range(0, 501)]`. Это и красивее, и программа будет работать быстрее. - Иначе все правильно.

Comment: @MarianD спасибо, исправил